# Blender workflow with model cad type files?

Tags: modeling

What is the best workflow for working with Autodesk Inventor and or Revit files in Blender? It appears that you can use STL. files for 3D Printing in Blender, however whenever I have tried to import and 3D Print a Model I have had very little success on import with the model broken to the point where I found it more time efficient to just rebuild the model.

Comment: Depends upon what file formats Inventor and Revit take.

Answer (score 4):

You can't "create" any other file than .blend, but you can export (copy-paste from blender official page):

> "Blender comes packed with import/export support for many different
>   programs.
>
> Including:
>
> Image JPEG, JPEG2000, PNG, TARGA, OpenEXR, DPX, Cineon, Radiance HDR,
>   SGI Iris, TIFF Video AVI, MPEG and Quicktime (on OSX). 3D 3D Studio
>   (3DS), COLLADA (DAE), Filmbox (FBX), Autodesk (DXF), Wavefront (OBJ),
>   DirectX (x), Lightwave (LWO), Motion Capture (BVH), SVG, Stanford PLY,
>   STL, VRML, VRML97, X3D."

Now you should see in the software in question documentation which files can be imported. Hoping there will be a match.

Very important complement to the answer: there's a lot of import/export plugins that are not available in Blender by default (by a way there's some that are available in the official built, but they are not enabled). The list is here (I'm pretty sure that this is not a 100% complete list...)

[List of import/export Blender plugins](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export)

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends on exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish which is often times dictated by the tools and resources that you are limited to.

If you are just trying to prepare a 3D Model for 3D Printing using a file originally created in an Autodesk program start by making sure the files are saved in a .stl file format before you import into Blender. More information on this can be found at this link here https://www.sculpteo.com/en/tutorial/prepare-your-model-3d-printing-blender/

You might need some add-ons because although Blender's polygon modeling is very efficient, it is comparatively weak in terms of its built in parametric modeling capabilities. For more information check the link here [Is blender actually useable for engineering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53293/is-blender-actually-useable-for-engineering)