# Making Diagrams and Blueprints for Engineering

Tags: add-on, workflow

In comparison, a lot of Autocad products are based on Architecture and Engineering, like making graphs and complex but easy to read blueprints.

Does blender have any such features, or are there any relevant plugins?

If you know of them, please give a link to the appropriate documentation and a brief overview of how these features work.

Comment: Blender is not designed to be a CAD type program and as such doesn't do these things well. It is designed for authoring content for artistic/entertainment purposes rather than for engineering, so if you are looking for an open source alternative to Autocad, blender isn't really a good option.

Comment: you may find https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53293/is-blender-actually-useable-for-engineering helpful

Comment: As mentioned Blender is not at all adequate as an engineering or CAD application. You may look into Freestyle renders for "blueprint like" rendering

Comment: I agree with what others have commented. But don't get the wrong idea - you can certainly model a house in Blender, as well as render blueprints. But not on the level of a professional architect. More like, on the level of an artist doing architectural *visualization*.

Comment: The [measureit addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb1U7g4JFbA) is probably the most relevant to what you want.